# referencing documents only by the mongo objectID?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

is it possible to reference another value other than the mongo generated _id?

User Model

```
uid: {type: String, required: true},
channel_pub: {type: String},
channel_groups: [{type: String}],
auth_key: {type: String},
channels: [{
    name: {
        type: String,
        ref: 'channel'
    }
}]
```

Channel Model

```
name: {type: String, required: true},
uid: [{
    type: String,
    ref: 'user',
    required: true
}]
```

I am trying to reference the actual channel name in the user document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [Populate Virtuals](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) since mongoose 4.5.0 :

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    uid: { type: String, required: true }
}, {
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true
    }
});

var ChannelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    uid: [{
        type: String,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    }]
});

UserSchema.virtual('channels.data', {
    ref: 'Channel',
    localField: 'channels.name',
    foreignField: 'name'
});
```

Here the local field is `channels.name`, the `Channel` object will be populated in `channels.data`.

For instance a find with `channels.data` populated :

```
User.find({}).populate('channels.data').exec(function(error, res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
});
```

will give :

```
[{
    "_id": "588a82ff7fe89686fd2210b0",
    "uid": "user1",
    "channels": [{
        "data": {
            "_id": "588a80fd7fe89686fd2210a8",
            "name": "channel1",
            "uid": []
        },
        "name": "channel1"
    }, {
        "data": {
            "_id": "588a80fd7fe89686fd2210a9",
            "name": "channel2",
            "uid": []
        },
        "name": "channel2"
    }],
    "id": "588a82ff7fe89686fd2210b0"
}
...
]
```

Comment: when I specify anything other than 'channels.data' it provides me with the data correctly but its as a separate attribute. For example if I was to make that just 'details' it would make an array of all the channels from the channels colletion. but when I have it like your selection because those are the desired results, I do not get anything returned at all

Comment: Sorry, I dont quite understand, do you want to change your populate field from channel.data to details ? If not, what would be the new model ?

Comment: No I wanted it exactly how you have it, it is just not populating the channels with the data like above in your expected results. I tried it with a different attribute .populate('details') and .virtual('details'). The data appears but its a seperate array as 'details' so I know its pulling the data properly from the other channel its just not populating it correctly. @bertrand

Comment: I've created a gist with the full code with input provided : https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/b982a3362cc190dcb2eddcd61c68d828. Maybe you're worried about `console.log(res)` ? I update to `console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));`